# C# Thread - Как мне получить ссылку на поток внутри этого самого потока?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Как получить ссылку на экземпляр Thread внутри этого же new Thread?

Comment: никак. но не факт, что решения нет. код покажете? кстати, а зачем вам это?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.currentthread?view=net-5.0 ?

Comment: Зачем мне это, - так как мне необходимо остановить этот поток с другого потока, нужно получить на него ссылку

Comment: А как остановить?

Comment: Чую [Thread.Abort](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.abort?view=net-5.0) - однако, он уже не поддерживается. Делайте правильно: [Cancellation in Managed Threads](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads) - передавайте в поток CancellationToken. И вообще, используйте Task'и. [TPL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl)

Comment: Вам не должно хотеться оборвать поток по многим причинам. Объясните свою настоящую задачу.

Comment: @VladD к примеру, с зависшими системными вызовами в линуксе - по другому бороться нельзя.

Comment: @Blackmeser: Зависший системный вызов? Неужели возможно убить поток, находящийся в режиме ядра? о_О Не знал. А если он в данный момент модифицирует внутренние структуры ядра?

Comment: @VladD а какая разница? Если поток завис намертво на системном вызове, сам процесс убивать безопаснее?

Comment: @Blackmeser: Подозреваю, что если один поток процесса висит в системным вызове, то и процесс убить не получится — ведь для этого надо убить все его потоки.

Comment: @Blackmeser: А так да. Ну вот допустим, вы убили нативный поток, который только что взял и ещё не отпустил heap lock. После этого любой нативный new и delete в любом потоке зависнет навсегда.

Answer (score 0):

```
//выделить место под ссылку для контролируемого потока.
Thread controlled_thread;

//получить ссылку на текущий поток.
controlled_thread = Thread.CurrentThread;

//прервать работу приостановленного потока (разумеется из другого потока)
controlled_thread.Interrupt();
```

Comment: `Interrupt()` не каждый поток сможет прервать, а только тот, который находится в состоянии `WaitSleepJoin`. Но, возможно, автору вопроса это подойдёт.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov поэтому я указал что это для "приостановленного потока", жаль что нет некого Thread.Kill()